# Probability of choosing third card at random

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, card-games

> There is a standard deck of cards and two of the cards are chosen at random. Compute the probability of choosing a third card at random whose number is in between the numbers of initially chosen cards.

Edit: A standard deck of cards has 52 cards, from A to K with spades, hearts, diamonds and clubs.

Comment: Any thoughts?  Hint:  one of the three must be between the other two (assuming you have ordered the cards from $1$ to $52$).

Comment: Is only the value of the cards meant, or are they numbered as lulu assumes ?

Comment: Nopes, its only values

Comment: @lulu Two cards can have the same number.

Comment: So, the order is $A,2,...,10,J,Q,K$ , right ?

Comment: @DonThousand  Well, it's a choice.  Some people rank the suits which would order the entire deck.

Comment: Yup, two cards can have same numbers as in a standard deck there are four cards for every number. @Peter right!

Comment: If the first two cards are given, we can easily count how many cards satisfy the desired property.

Comment: yeah, the solution requires proper formulation of the conditional probability that the first two cards are given which themselves are chosen at random.

Comment: @PrabhatSharma I guess you search for an easy solution because you should have no problem to solve the exercise by just considering all cases which would be cumbersome.

Comment: Assuming that "between" requires that all three values be distinct: there's no difficulty computing the probability that the three values are distinct, after which my first hint applies.

Comment: Counting cases seems cumbersome to me that's why I was thinking that maybe we can formulate this in this way: suppose we take 3 random varibles x1, x2 and x3 denoting the card drawn at first, second and thrd turn. Then we've to calculate P(X3|X2;X1) = sum(p(x3=i | X2<i ; X1>i))

Comment: @lulu Its not the same because it may happen that the first two cards are different themselves and also different than the third but both of them have a greater number than the thrid.

Comment: I don't understand.  Conditioned on the fact that the three values are distinct, one of the values is between the other two.  Symmetry tells us...

Answer (score 1):

If the value of the last card has to be between the values of the first two, the three cards must have distinct numbers. There are ${13 \choose 3} = 286$ possible card combinations. There are two ways to draw each of these combinations: either pick the lowest number first, or pick the highest number first. Furthermore, each card can have one of four suits, so there are $4^3 = 64$ valid suit combinations. The probability of choosing a third card whose number is in between the numbers of initially chosen cards, thus equals:

$$\frac{286 \cdot 2 \cdot 64}{52 \cdot 51 \cdot 50} = \frac{36608}{132600} \approx 0.276$$

Alternatively, we can immediately calculate the probability $p$ of drawing three distinct values. We find:

$$p = \frac{52}{52} \frac{48}{51} \frac{44}{50} \approx 0.828$$

Since there are three possible numbers to be drawn last, we simply have to divide by three. The probability of choosing a third card whose number is in between the numbers of initially chosen cards, thus equals:

$$\frac{p}{3} \approx \frac{0.828}{3} = 0.276$$